# How many Tasks are too many

Tags: c#

I am working on a spaceship shooter style game.  In the game there are slow moving missiles that I run on different tasks.

```
Task t4 = new Task(() => fireShipCannons());
```

They don't do much; just move a small bitmap across the screen.  Usually it is a for loop with 30 iterations.  The problem is that the timing is off and some tasked seem to take priority over others.  I also many be important to note that to control the speed of the missiles I am using Thread.Sleep(100).  Because of this slowing down, the method will run for a few seconds.

I am using c#, .net, Windows Form Application

I have spent hours thinking about how to reword this, and I think it is worded correctly.  The problem I was having was broad; so yes, the question may be a bit broad.  I got a great answer!  Does that not indicate that the question was asked correctly?

Comment: You shouldn't spin up a Task per each object in the game. Actually, there's usually a single loop to control all the changes in the game. Just for simplicity, the loop looks something like: 
while (isGameRunning)
{
    Update(DateTime.UtcNow);
    Render();
}

You should just know the actual speed vector for each object in the game, and calculate the new position in the Update method. Then the Render method will draw the current state - and no matter how much time has passed since the last update, as the distance will be adjusted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are already using `Task`s (good), you can simply make them [async Tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx) and use `await Task.Delay(time)`.

```
    async Task fireShipCannons(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < distance; i++) {
           await Task.Delay(100, ct);
           drawBitmap(i);
        }
    }
```

This way you will not tie up 1 thread for every bullet. Most likely your tasks are currently slow because you reach the limit of your threadpool, so this should be a lot faster. But additionally, you should also check if `Task.Delay` has taken more than the 100 ms you suggested. If it did, draw the bullet 2 spots further instead of 1, and reschedule accordingly.

```
    async Task fireShipCannons(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        var start = DateTime.Now;
        while (bullet.isOnscreen) {
           drawBitmap(bullet);
           var sleep = (start.Add(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100.0)) - DateTime.Now);
           if (sleep.Milliseconds > 0) {
               Task.Delay(sleep, ct);
           }
           iter = (int)((DateTime.Now - start).TotalMilliseconds / 100 + 0.5);
           bullet.moveSteps(iter); // move it iter steps.
           var start = start.AddMilliseconds(100 * it);
       }
    }
```

Lastly, it might be a good idea to not hammer your draw function with new calls for every bullet, but instead combine all bullets/changes into a single render function that calculate all changes and sends them off in one go. But that depend on how your draw function itself is implemented.

Comment: This just isn't going to scale up well enough to do animations for a game, nor is there sufficient precision in `Task.Delay`

Comment: @Servy `Task.Delay` is equally accurate as `Thread.Sleep`. Both are based on the system clock, and are accurate up to 15ms in practice. This solution at least wont tie up a thread for every bullet. You can add tons of additional logic to calculate how long to sleep next, how long we have been asleep (and skip iterations if it was over 100ms) etc. But that's beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: You're quite right that `Thread.Sleep` is also an inadequate tool for timing animations; this is evidenced by the OP mentioning one of his major problems being that the timings are all off, and that being a core problem he needs to fix, that you aren't addressing.  Not tying up a whole thread for each item being animated is indeed much better, but it doesn't change the fact that, while better, it's still far short of adequate.

Comment: @Servy The part that might not scale is hammering `drawBitmap(i);` for every object, but `Task`s should have no problem with this even if you run 10.000 of them together. If you want to suggest the OP to completely overhaul his design, feel free to write an answer that does so, i'm merely showing how to solve his current problem.

Comment: Also, even a refitted design can still benefit from using the technique described above, using `await Task.Delay`. Funny enough the 15ms accuracy comes up to 60fps, enough for most games. So instead of `drawBitmap(i);` you replace that with `updateAllBitmap();`.

Comment: But your answer *doesn't* solve his current problem.  Your answer suggests a solution that won't work, for regularly the same reasons that the OP's own code won't work.

Comment: A game is going to require pretty radically different design in order to scale sufficiently well, so no, he can't just improve on your techniques.  In order to scale well enough to make a game, he'll need to throw out the whole design and use a game design framework.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the machine and the number of threads it can support. On the other hand, I don't think that using Thread.Sleep it is a good practice, why don't you just change the distance, in pixels, that the object travels every millisecond?

Comment: I accidently clicked here